# Display Name instead of Id in a GridView using stored procedure and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a created a GridView in ASP.NET which is databound to a stored procedure.

In my stored procedure I have `customerID` which is from another table. How I can display name of the customer instead of the `id` number? Could anyone help me please?

This my code

```
private void BindGrid()
{        
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Counry"))
        {               
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");             

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to show us some sample output data from your SP. And the markup for your GridView. PS its highly recommended **not** to use [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Maybe even the contents of your SP.

Comment: This should be done in the stored procedure - it should return not only the `customerId`, but also the customer's name and any other information you might need to show

Answer (score 1):

you may use join or subquery in your stored procedure to get customers' names if both tables have CustomerId column (column names may be different, values must match).
an example;

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, o.OrderId 
FROM Orders AS o 
INNER JOIN Customers AS c ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
```

you can change table and column names as yours, also if you need to see all records included NULL values, may try OUTER JOIN

Comment: Thank you , i will try .. so only i need change the SP not the C# code yes ?

Comment: then you have to use CustomerName (or your column name) in your GridView columns if you don't populate columns automatically.

Comment: @Dev it depends, you have to show us for anyone to be able to give a conclusive answer.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: then you need to give more information. your sp, the information about your table, also about GridView. and the error message if you have